# FL studio as VST plugin into Virtual DJ 8

Tags: software, electronic-music, daw, vst, fl-studio

I tried to integrate FL Studio as a VST plugin into Virtual DJ 8 but when I activate the plugin there is no sound from the song that was originally playing. Also the BPMs from Virtual DJ do not sync with the FL Studio plugin and the platters do not activate automatically or in sync.

I use Sony Acid Music Studio together with the FL Studio plugin and it works seamlessly. How can I do the same when using the FL Studio plugin in Virtual DJ 8?

Answer (score 1):

Try Virtual DJ 8 as a vst in FL Studio. That will help. For more info
http://www.virtualdj.com/forums/5121/VirtualDJ_Plugins/_VST_BEGINNER_GUIDE_-_What_is_VST__how_to_use_etc_.html

Comment: This seems to be different from what the asker is trying to do. Can you give some more detail as to why you recommend this and how it will help?

Comment: Yeah, i am so sorry about this. I didnt read in correctly. I aplogize for this.